# Is it possible to take the class method as comparator?

Tags: c++, class, comparator

I have a private comparator in Level class:

```
   bool positionCmp(Entity* a, Entity* b);
```

and when I try to use this in another Level class method:

```
void Level::drawEntities(std::vector<Entity*> entities)
{
    sort(entities.begin(), entities.end(), positionCmp);
    for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); ++i) entities[i]->draw();
}
```

Visual Studio 2019 compiler says:
`'Level::positionCmp': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`.
If I add the '&', I getting `'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression`

```
void Level::drawEntities(std::vector<Entity*> entities)
    {
        sort(entities.begin(), entities.end(), &positionCmp);
        for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); ++i) entities[i]->draw();
    }
```

What should I do?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the member function `static`, and use either syntax.

A member function `bool positionCmp(Entity* a, Entity* b);` in class `Level` effectively has a third implied parameter with type `Level*` for the `this` pointer, even if the definition doesn't actually use `this` or any members of `this`. So it can't be called without an argument for "the current object" - either via an `level.positionCmp(a, b)` or `p->positionCmp(a, b)` expression, or using the implied `this->positionCmp(a, b)` within another non-static member function of `Level` or a derived class.

The `static` keyword says that the function doesn't need a `this` object, and so the function can act as an ordinary two-argument function like you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You would need something like this:

```
std::sort(entities.begin(), entities.end(),
  [this](Entity* a, Entity* b) { return positionCmp(a, b); });
```

This assumes that `positionCmp` actually refers to some data members of `Level`, and needs access to a `Level` instance to do its work. If it does not - if all it needs is two `Entity` instances passed as parameters - then declare it static, as in

```
static bool positionCmp(Entity* a, Entity* b);
```

Then your original version of `sort(entities.begin(), entities.end(), positionCmp)` would work as is.